# What is this leaf disease on the Janet Blair?

Tags: diseases, flowers, leaf

I planted a Janet Blair (type of Azalea) last year and since that time it has not been doing well. New leaves are coming out but soon half the leaves have some discoloration. I don’t know what is it. One side of the plant seems to have died but the other side is still getting new leaves but catching that disease. [[image][image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two guesses. Based on your pictures and my [favorite azalea diagnostic guide](https://www.se-ars.org/uploads/3/9/7/2/39727246/eb1229.pdf) from Washington State University, I think it's either **marginal leaf necrosis** or **fungus leaf spot**.  They both cause the plant's leaves to die from the tips and edges back

**Marginal leaf necrosis** isn't a disease so much as the plant being too stressed.  There are a lot of things that can cause that! The linked guide lists *all* of these as possible causes:

> - Cold damage occurs when temperatures dip to near or below the hardiness limit of the plant. May be accentuated by wind and drought,
>   especially in eastern Washington.
> - Drought, especially while the plant is in active growth or the foliage is in soft growth, and on newly established plants.
> - High amounts of salts in the soil caused by excessive use of soluble fertilizers. Very common close to the house where the eaves
>   protect soil from rain, and along the dripline of the house where salt
>   (fertilizer) concentrations are high when the plant is in soft growth.
> - Root damage due to poor drainage, planting too deep, physical injury to root system, or disease.
> - Girdling due to weevil feeding on bark and/or roots.
> - Nutrient deficiency

If this azalea was planted a year ago and has been struggling since then, I suspect there could be something wrong with it's environment.  I see on this [Janet Blair guide](https://plants.buyallseasons.com/12250004/Plant/7823/Janet_Blair_Rhododendron/) that they want partial shade and well drained, acidic soil.  Is the plant getting that?  Watered and fertilized appropriately?  Is the soil fertile and of good quality, and do you *know* that it is (soil test!)?  The necrosis also tends to be slightly quarantined and bordered by the leaf's veins.  These example images show that:

[image: Image of two leaves with brown borders and living centers]
[image: Image of azalea plant showing necrotic tips on several leaves]

**Fungus Leaf Spot** is a fungal infection. The above linked guide gives us more specific guidance on this diagnostic:

> **Symptoms**: Spots are irregular in size and color (Fig. 8). Some have
> red-brown borders with silvery gray centers. Very small black dots
> (fruiting structures of fungi) are sometimes visible in the center of
> the spot or in concentric rings. These fungi commonly enter through
> wounds.
> **Cause**: The fungi Phyllosticta, Septoria, Pestalotia are
> commonly the causal agents of this malady. Remove and destroy affected
> leaves. Spray with a registered fungicide after flowering and repeat
> at 10–14 day intervals until dry weather begins. It is usually
> advisable to apply a spreader-sticker with the fungicide to hold the
> fungicide on the leaves during rains.

To me, the whiteness on the leaves in your images look like sun bleaching after the tissue has been dead for a while.  However, you can take a close look to see if it does appear to be a fungus.  A good magnifying glass can help with this.  I've also found that I can 'clean' some of the fungus off of the leaf by rubbing it with a wet rag.  It's not enough to help the plant but helps you establish that there's some white stuff on the leaf (fungus), not the leaf itself turning white (bleaching).

[image: Image of two azalea leaves turned halfway brown with shite splotches from the tips and edges towards the petiole]

Good luck with your Janet Blair!

Comment: Will try some options. Not a slam dunk. The Azelea (not Janet Blair) next to it is doing fine. Could be stress or soil related i suspect.